# Sqlite Statement with variable Syntax

Tags: database, sqlite, dynamic, syntax

I need to run dynamically INSERT and CREATE Sqlite statements.

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Menu"+counter+" (itemid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, test TEXT, type TEXT, table TEXT)";

"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Menu"+counter+" (itemid , test, type, table) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

I got on both statements a syntax error if i try to run.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLError
SQLError.SYNTAX_ERR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` is a reserved keyword, and needs to be quoted in both statements if used as a field name.

I suggest you find another name, but to keep it, surround it with `"`;

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Menu'+counter+
  ' (itemid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, test TEXT, type TEXT, "table" TEXT)'
```